# Différentes manières de dire « manger » de façon familière

Tags: registre-familier

J'ai eu une petite discussion avec mes collègues sur les niveaux des différentes manières de dire « manger » de façon familière.
Nous avons « bouffer », « grailler », « béqueter ».
Certains disent que la seule différence est que certains sont plus locaux que d'autre. « Bouffer » serait plus national et  « béqueter » du nord.

Sauriez-vous d'où proviennent chacun des verbes et s'ils comportent aussi des différences au niveau de leur utilisation ?
Connaissez-vous d'autres verbes familiers pour dire « manger » ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je n'avais jamais entendu "tchapper" et je suis sur Toulouse depuis plus de 15 ans ^^

Comment: _Se taper/faire un kebab._ En ce qui concerne "grailler", c'est issu de la banlieue parisienne, en général ça part de là, puis 2, 3 clips de rap, et le tout s'étend aux banlieues de France. "On va graille un grec", c'est typique parisien.

Comment: Grailler est plus ancien que le rap !!!  Le mot existait bien avant la notion de banlieue telle que nous la connaissons aujourd'hui.

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda C'est le problème des parlers régionaux qui se disparaissent. Dans mon enfance - qui remonte à loin - on parlait « patois » (en BCBG on dirait occitan de nos jours) encore sur le marché Arnaud Bernard (pas seulement, bien sûr mais c'est celui que je fréquentais).

Comment: @Laure ouai mais je mais je ne l'ai même pas entendu de mon père ou mon grand-père qui parlent occitan

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda On ne peut pas tous connaitre tous les mots.. et puis je suis peut-être plus vieux que ton grand-père !

Comment: @Laure Haha, peut-être, je pense pas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les termes proviennent de l'argot et sont toujours plus ou moins argotiques ; de même que les termes supplémentaires dont il est question dans la seconde partie de la question ils sont tous plus en moins entachés de vulgarité, tout au moins pour les français les plus exigeants en matière de langue française. Voyons d'abord un ngram pour les fréquences comparées de leur emploi ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bouffer%2Cgrailler%2Cbecqueter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbouffer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrailler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecqueter%3B%2Cc0)).
« Bouffer » est tout à fait national, je crois être assez sûr de ça. C'est un terme populaire pour le TLFi ; il a possiblement gagné en tolérance dans les décennies passées pour devenir seulement familier.
« Grailler » est bien familier ; c'est tout simplement un synonyme de « manger » avec une possible [connotation](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/grailler/) (répété ci-dessous) ;ce terme est énormément moins courant que « bouffer », lequel se compare à « becqueter » de la même façon (voir ngram précédent) ;

> Le verbe grailler est employé dans le langage familier pour décrire l'acte de s'alimenter. C'est un terme plutôt bienveillant, qui désigne un repas agréable et appétissant, souvent à base de nourriture riche. 
>   Exemple : Il a préparé un festin. On va bien grailler.

Chose surprenante, le terme « becqueter » est considéré comme de la langue courante par le TLFi, pas un terme familier ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/becqueter)). Je le considère personnellement comme vulgaire, argotique.

Voici d'autres termes, avec certaines de leur connotations particulières ;

- tortorer : populaire [ref](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tortorer/78573)
- bâfrer fam. et pop., manger gloutonnement et avec excès
- boulotter Arg. signifie tout simplement  « manger »
- croûter  Arg. manger
- briffer Pop. Manger avidement et gloutonnement.
- casser la croûte : se restaurer, manger ; signifiait encore récemment « manger un morceau » (1798 casser la croûte « manger un morceau » (Ac.)) mais le sens a été détourné.

Comment: Je n'avais pas pensé à regarder sur Google trend, béqueter à bien l'air d'être propre au nord de la France https://trends.google.fr/trends/explore?date=all&geo=FR&q=bouffer,grailler,becqueter

Comment: Le verbe _grailler_ est bien plus courant que vous ne le pensez. En termes d'argot issu typiquement de la rue, je pense que le TLFi n'est clairement pas une source, les réseaux sociaux en disent bien plus à ce niveau. Ce n'est qu'une question de génération

Comment: On ne peut établir aucun rapport entre le fait qu'un mot soit dans le TLF et sa fréquence. Combien de bons dictionnaires ont oublié de mots ! Par ailleurs la rue fait la langue, plus que les dictionnaires et l'académie française.

Comment: @Kenichi-san Si l'on se fie à l'ngram dans ma réponse, qui montre qu'il n'est même pas aussi important que « becqueter », lequel, comme l'information trouvée [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37718/diff%c3%a9rentes-mani%c3%a8res-de-dire-manger-de-fa%c3%a7on-famili%c3%a8re/37722?noredirect=1#comment75533_37722) le montre n'est utilisé presque que dans le Nord. Apparemment, il ne serait pas beaucoup utilisé. C'est indubitable, je tiens compte de cette évolution en notant que certains termes gagnent en tolérance. (champ 1)

Comment: @Kenichi-san  Évidemment the TLFi n'est pas une source pour ceux qui rejettent la culture traditionnelle, ceux qui n'ont pas eu l'opportunité de la découvrir, et qui n'ont donc pas eu l'opportunité d'apprendre seulement ce qu'il y a de bon dedans. (end)

Comment: @ Laure On ne peut pas suspecter constamment que le dictionnaire est en erreur ; oui, il pourrait y avoir une erreur ; cet état de chose (pas d'entrée) est bien une indication : elle est corroborée dans une grande mesure par l'ngram qui montre combien  « bouffer » est extrêmement plus courant. Bien sûr, si l'on doit laisser au plus mauvais le soin de nous dire comment penser, je ne vois même plus le besoin de passer des années sur les bancs des écoles pour apprendre une langue ; il n'y a qu'à se laisser aller au sirop de la rue.

Comment: Ngrams (corpus écrits) et le TLF (1789-1960)  ne sont pas des sources utiles pour le langage familier post 20e siècle.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Cela est concevable  pour le TLFi mais pour les ngrams, le matériel écrit ne reflète-t-il pas le langage parlé ? ces ngrams sont le résultat d'analyses qui sont faite jusqu'en 2008 ; Qu'est-ce que onze années dans l'évolution d'une langue ? La période de temps reconnue par les experts pour qu'un changement réel soit significatif est 25 années.

Comment: @LPH Les temps ne sont plus les mêmes, avec la révolution numérique, la culture du buzz, et Internet, une journée suffit à changer l'évolution d'une langue. Par exemple, le verbe _zlataner_ qui a été inséré dans certains dictionnaires, suite au buzz du joueur Zlatan Ibrahimovic à cette période. Si la langue française doit prendre en compte les phénomènes de mode qui lui sont associés, alors votre point de vue d'une langue statique ne fonctionne plus

Comment: @Kenichi-san Je ne pense pas que mon point de vue soit celui du conservateur qui veut à tout prix s'accrocher au passé mais c'est celui de ceux qui ne voient aucun but dans l'addition au langage d'une multitude de formes **qui n'ajoutent rien**, sinon de la vulgarité, sous  prétexte qu'il faut suivre les caprices des uns et les modes des autres. Toute cette culture dite numérique n'existe pas, c'est la culture qui continue, bien ou mal comme d'habitude, et elle n'est que diffusée plus rapidement à cause du numérique ; cette nouvelle révolution est montée à la tête de beaucoup de monde.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Et en plus grailler se trouve dans le TLF, je n'avais pas pris la peine de vérifier :-!. [« Grailler, verbe intrans.,arg. Manger. »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grailler).

Comment: @Fólkvangr Oh ! Oui ! C'est toujours vulgaire pour beaucoup de Monde ! Je ne l'ai pas encore vu la publicité « Venez bouffer chez Maxim's, c'est sensas ! »…

Comment: LPH, tu sembles te considérer comme étant parmi *les plus exigeants en matière de langue française*. Pourquoi utilises-tu alors *décade* pour *décennie* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il me semble que c'est correct, ça serait un synonyme selon le dictionnaire, mais c'est à cause de l'anglais plutôt ; c'est inconscient ; de toute façon, être exigeant ne signifie pas que l'on ne peut pas se tromper ici et là ou avoir acquis de temps en temps une notion hors normes, mais ce ne sera que rarement le cas ; ça ne veut pas dire que l'on n'a plus rien à apprendre non plus et j'apprends tous les jours de nouvelles choses, même des choses qui viennent remplacer ce qui jusqu'à présent semblait convenir mais qui n'est plus de si bon gout au vu d'autres opinions.

Comment: http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/decade-decennie-a5526457 Il te reste aussi à apprendre ce que signifie *vulgaire* en français moderne.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh ! Non ! Pas vulgaire, vulgaire c'est un dégout avec une armée et une marine…

Comment: La religion fait dans la censure bien pensante, je trouve ça pire encore mais à chacun son truc. C'est vrai que dans [_La Grande Bouffe_](https://youtu.be/cuqZlOHnJNw) on parle de _séminaire gastronomique_, ça n'en est pas moins vulgaire... bof. Je vais peut-être visionner ça à nouveau par curiosité pour voir si on dit _bouffer_ une seule fois... Mais non, aucune de tes affirmations en commentaire ne permet de déduire que c'est vulgaire aujourd'hui, d'accord _bouffer_ + organe (génital) est complètement vulgaire. TGIS.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Disons que ça ne l'est pas pour une majorité qui n'a aucun souci de préserver un langage bien châtié, qui monte et qui descend avec la vague comme le bouchon, et que ça l'est pour d'autres, qui n'ont pas encore disparu ; pourquoi penser aux uns et oublier les autres ? Je donne bien dans cette unilatéralité mais c'est une erreur qui se corrige.  Il n'y a pas de meilleur moyen pour voir ce qu'un peuple fait de son esprit que de passer en revue ses créations.

Comment: Tous sont libres de s'approprier la langue, on peut trouver le résultat douteux mais les différents niveaux et registres, les différents sociolectes etc. existent concurremment. Il est possible de nuancer, comme tu l'as fait dans ton dernier commentaire.

Answer (score 7):

Je ne connais pas de différences régionales dans l'emploi des mots « bouffer », « becqueter » et « grailler ». Il est possible que certains soient plus répandus que d'autres selon les régions, il faudrait une étude plus fine.

**Bouffer** est d'origne onomatopéique, le radical *buff* évoquant le gonflement « et suggère plus particulièrement l'action de lâcher de l'air après l'avoir gardé la bouche close et gonflée ». Le sens particulier de « gonfler les joues par excès d'aliments (16<sup>e</sup> siècle) est sorti d'usage mais a donné par métonymie celui de mange goulûment. » (DHLF)

**Becqueter** vient de bec, désignation populaire de « bouche ».

**Grailler** vient de l'ancien français *graillon* (rôtir sur un gril), la *graille* (nourriture) est apparu au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, et de là « grailler » (1944). (Source DHLF).

**Tchaper**, par contre, est un usage local du sud-ouest de la France. Le mot vient de l'occitan *chapar* [tʃapaʁ] - (Bernard Vavassori - *Petit précis de parler méridional*).  Ça a plus le sens de « dévorer » que de manger.

---

À ceux-ci j'en ajoute deux qui sont assez fréquents me semble-t-il.

**Bâfrer** (1740), de *baufrer* (1507) dérivé de l'onomatopée *baf* qui évoque ce qui est épais, boursouflé, gonflé, puis le fait de manger gloutonnement, les joues étant gonflées de nourriture. (Source DHLF)

**Boulotter** (bouloter). L'histoire de ce mot, trouvée dans le *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey) me semble assez intéressante pour être partagée ici.

> L'histoire du mot est complexe et mal connue. Nous pensons qu'il s'agit d'un même verbe boulotter, apparu vers 1830, intransitif, avec le sens 2 [*] et une sujet personnel (*Je boulotte*, je me laisse vivre). Ce sens s'est bien maintenu tout au long du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle ; il est largement attesté dans H. Monnier (*Les bas-fonds*, *passim*) et encore dans Zola (« Pendant une année encore la maison boulotta », *L'assomoir*) et Courteline.
>   Vers 1840-1845, deux sens se greffent sur le premier. L'idée de « vivoter plutôt bien » engendre naturellement celles de « avoir du travail », « avoir à manger ». La première est bien attestée dans H. Monnier ; c'est très probablement *boulotter* en ce sens qui a fourni *boulot*, travail, mais s'est transformé en *boulonner*, familier. La seconde notion, celle de « manger à sa faim », a à peu près éliminé les deux autres sens ; elle a certainement été favorisée dans sa diffusion par la proximité de *bouffer*. Le verbe est à l'origine un diminutif de *bouler* « rouler comme une boule » (Cf. « Ça roule ! », attesté en ce sens en 1800.

*sens **1**. transitif : manger.  sens **2**. intransitif : aller doucement, suivre son cours de façon satisfaisante (sens disparu au 20<sup>e</sup> siècle).

**Se taper** utilisé uniquement avec un complément (« j'ai bien envie de m'taper un burger »). Vient du sens sorti d'usage de « taper quelque chose »  qui signifiait  « se servir abondamment de quelque chose ». (DHLF)

On dit aussi  ***se taper la cloche***. Pour l'instant je n'ai pas trouvé de source à laquelle je ferais pour dire pourquoi « la cloche » (cloche = la tête ne me convainc pas).

---

Et d'autres qui me semblent moins courants :

**Jouer des dominos**. En argot les dominos ce sont les dents (par analogie de forme et de couleur avec les plaquettes du jeu du même nom et qui autrefois étaient en ivoire). Au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle on employait l'expression argotique « Jouer des dominos » pour dire manger. (*Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel*)

> «C'est affaire à toi, me dit-il, comme tu joues des dominos, à te voir, on croirait que tu morfiles dans de la crignole » ([Les mémoires de Vidocq](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38059/38059-h/38059-h.htm), Tome 3)

**Se caler les joues** (se les caler) :
Apparu au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle « par extension du sens de caler qui signifie "installer confortablement" » (DHLF)

> «... il est expressément convenu que "tous les mecs seront cuistots, chacun son tour", et qu'ils seront condamnés "à bouffer de leur tambouille au lieu de se les caler avec des frites,..." » (Roland Dorgelès, [*Les croix de bois*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1WQOCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25&dq=%22se%20les%20caler%22&source=bl&ots=7yAv3ygUMo&sig=ACfU3U1P6PYN_Ha4tf645RH5lGkqtRqJkw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiapYzRveTjAhWyA2MBHUi4DCY4ChDoATADegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22se%20les%20caler%22&f=false))

**S'en mettre (s'en foutre) plein la lampe** expression datant du début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle et qui se rattache au sens argotique de *lampe* * « estomac ». (DHLF)

*Sens argotique qui dérive du sens initial du mot *lampe* : récipient contenant un liquide.

> Comme un chien, comme un porc, comme une bête, je mange, je mange, je bouffe, je bâfre et je me gave, à m'en faire éclater, à me faire crever. Je m'en mets plein la panse, plein la gueule, plein la lampe. Je veux m'enfoncer dans le manger, m'y vautrer, m'y noyer. (Rachel Hausfater *[Yankov](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Dp6jAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&dq=%22plein%20la%20lampe%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiknLu0x-TjAhWj2uAKHUIWDegQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22plein%20la%20lampe%22&f=false)*.

Il existe énormément d'expressions familières pour dire *manger* et ma réponse ne saurait être exhaustive. Un petit aperçu dans  [*Le Bouquet des expressions imagées*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XoF1DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT212&dq=%22manger%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfteaxtuTjAhVRzBoKHcwjApsQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) de Sylvie Claval et Claude Duneton.

Comment: D'autres suggestions : *boustifailler, casser la graine, grignoter, gueuletonner, picorer, ripailler, s’empiffrer, se goinfrer*.